# Cannot set property 'marginLeft' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Firstly, [>>>FIDDLE HERE<<<](http://jsfiddle.net/helisz/fgNdT/1/)

I put a series of divs in my webpage and used JavaScript to change their margins.

```
var inn = document.getElementsByClassName("line");
for (var i in inn) {
   inn[i].style.marginLeft=40+"px";
}
```

Although it changed my margins already, an error reported in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'marginLeft' of undefined
```

So rest of my codes couldn't be executed.

Could you please help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the properties that your loop iterates over:

```
0
1
2
3
4
length
```

A [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description) iterates over all the enumerable properties of an object. You shouldn't use it for array-like objects unless you really intend to do that.

`0` through `4` work, but `length` doesn't have a `style` attribute, which is what your error says.

Use a regular `for` loop instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inn.length; i++) {
    inn[i].style.marginLeft = 40 + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use for ... in ... it's slower and more error prone try this:

```
var inn = document.getElementsByClassName("line");
var i=0;
for (i=0;i<inn.length;i++) {
   inn[i].style.marginLeft=40+"px";
}
```

next one shows the for ... in ... I think it may include some things that aren't Elements so the .style is undefined.

```
for(i in inn){
  console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution which worked for me is instead of class name, try using by id. only when you explicitly don't need a class
change this line to

```
var inn = document.getElementsByClassName("line");
```

to

```
var inn = document.getElementById("line");
```

and definately make change in html file also.